# Difference between 'as' and 'so' in this sense

Tags: word-difference

> I voted Labour, **as** did my wife.
>
> I voted Labour, **so** did my wife.

I think both sentences are correct. Are there any nuances between these twos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, both words mean **in the same way**, but  [as](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as) is a conjunction and [so](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so) is an adverb. As a conjunction, **as** links the first and second clauses together. As an adverb, **so** does not provide a link: it merely modifies the second part of the sentence. As it stands, the second sentence is not grammatically correct because there is nothing to link the two parts of the sentence.

> I voted Labour, so did my wife. - *incorrect*
>   I voted Labour **and** so did my wife. - *correct*
>   I voted Labour: so did my wife. - *correct*
>   I voted Labour. So did my wife. - *correct*

Similarly, the conjunction **as** cannot be used **and**, or when there are two separate sentences:

> I voted Labour, as did my wife. - *correct*
>   I voted Labour **and** as did my wife. - *incorrect*
>   I voted Labour: as did my wife. - *incorrect*
>   I voted Labour. As did my wife. - *incorrect*

Note that most of these grammatically incorrect versions do occur in informal spoken English.